# Is there a limit to how long an if statement can be in Java?

Tags: java

I was working on a game called the L game. In the function to check for a win, I had an if statement like this:

```
if (buttons[i][0].getText().equals(colour)  || buttons[i][0].getText().equals("0") && buttons[i][1].getText().equals(colour)  || buttons[i][1].getText().equals("0") && buttons[i][2].getText().equals(colour)  || buttons[i][2].getText().equals("0") && buttons[i+1][2].getText().equals(colour)  || buttons[i+1][2].getText().equals("0") && !(buttons[i][0].getText().equals(colour) && buttons[i][1].getText().equals(colour) && buttons[i][2].getText().equals(colour) && buttons[i+1][2].getText().equals(colour))) {
        return false;
}
```

And this code didn't work. Not that I was getting an error, just it was not doing what it was supposed to do when a player won. However changed it to a few if statements in each other like this:

```
if (buttons[i][0].getText().equals(colour)  || buttons[i][0].getText().equals("0")) {
    if (buttons[i][1].getText().equals(colour)  || buttons[i][1].getText().equals("0")) {
        if (buttons[i][2].getText().equals(colour)  || buttons[i][2].getText().equals("0")) {
            if (buttons[i+1][2].getText().equals(colour)  || buttons[i+1][2].getText().equals("0")) {
               if (!(buttons[i][0].getText().equals(colour) && buttons[i][1].getText().equals(colour) && buttons[i][2].getText().equals(colour) && buttons[i+1][2].getText().equals(
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this does work.

Comment: The logic for these two blocks of code is completely different.

Comment: Technical answer: no. Practical answer: you don't worry about line lenght and code style for `javac`, it doesn't care. You worry about them because you and fellow developers need to be able to read your code. And this does not make for pleasant reading. Why use fully unrolled code rather than having a normal `boolean hasRightButtonText(Button[] buttons)` and an if that is just `if(hasRightButtonText(buttons)) { ... }`?

Comment: `a || b && c || d`is equivalent to `if a || (b && c) || d` not to `(a || b) && (c || d)`. Your first block is not equivalent to the second one.

Comment: A || B && C is equivalent to A || (B && C), not to (A || B) && C. Adding the parentheses makes it clear.

Comment: As sleepToken alluded to, `A || B && C || D` is not doing what you think it does, because operator precedence specifies that it means `A || (B && C) || D`, whereas you other `if` statement interpreted it as `(A || B) && (C || D)`. Precedence of `||` and `&&` confuses most people, so **always** use `()` parenthesis when mixing them in the same expression, to clarify what you wanted and to ensure you get that.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of  that.

Answer (score 4):

Your two code snippets behave differently not because you have exceeded some "maximum characters in an if statement" limit, but because `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`.

When you say:

```
A || B && C || D
```

You meant

```
(A || B) && (C || D)
```

But without any parentheses, Java thought you meant:

```
A || (B && C) || D
```

This is because `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`. It's kind of like how you do multiplication first, than addition.

That aside, there is theoretically no limit on how long an if condition can be. It is not specified in the Java Language Specification. As long as you have enough RAM for the compiler, disk space to store the source file, and time for the compilation process, your code should compile *eventually*, if we assume the compiler implements the spec perfectly.

This doesn't mean that you should be writing super long if statements, though. Code is not only read by computers. Arguably, it is more often read by *people* than computers. So please keep that in mind when writing code.

A first step to refactoring your code would be to write a method like this:

```
private bool isButton0(int x, int y) {
    return buttons[x][y].getText().equals("0");
}
```

so that you don't have to repeatedly say `buttons[i][1].getText().equals("0")`.